# vscode on mac is incorrectly highlighting text around text blocks

Tags: visual-studio-code

It is very annoying to see that background around code is lighter then the rest of the program. When the cursor moves the highlighting moves up and down to full window width. Can you please propose solution how to turn this highlighting off. Same problem is in output of task log, and in file explorer.

I have deleted all the settings and Application data and I have same problem. I have installed vscode on windows and I do not have this problem with same settings.

[image]

Comment: I'm on macOS and don't see this effect. Maybe something with your HW or a specific theme?

Comment: I have default theme and I have reinstalled vscode to be without extensions and wipeout all data, could be something in system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is an issue in Chromium.  You can work around this by starting VS Code with `--disable-gpu` from the command line.

Sean

Answer (score 0):

It appears this can be fixed for some users by selecting a different color profile in macOS display settings. Note that you have to change this separately for all monitors that you use.

[image]

For me, "Apple RGB" will show these blocks, and switching to "LED Cinema Display" or "iMac" solves the issue.

See also: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12473#issuecomment-269024219